# Required arguments are no longer mandatory in PHP?

Tags: php, function, error-handling, arguments

Example:

```
public function a($a, $b){

}


a();  // warning: missing arguments. why no fatal error???
```

If I try to force a fatal error

```
public function a($a, $b){

  if(!$a || !$b)  // <- notice undefined variable. wtf?
    throw new exception('!!!');
}

a();
```

I'm pretty sure this wasn't happening before :|

Comment: Your error reporting must be super suppressed, [because that's a fatal error](https://eval.in/201591)

Comment: its not, i have set it to -1

Comment: oh u mean the exception? yes that works but why do i get the notices? the variables are there :/